# Rails find query with no duplicates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How do I change the following bit of code so that I only have records with distinct `sender_id` and `message_id` combinations:

```
@roles = Role.find_all_by_simulation_id(session[:sim_id])
@messages = RolesMessages.find(:all, :conditions => ["sender_id IN (?) ", @roles.map(&:id)], :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@messages = RolesMessages.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT sender_id, message_id', :conditions => ["sender_id IN (?) ", @roles.map(&:id)], :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

Edit: now that I think of it, group by is probably a better option.
`:group => 'sender_id, message_id'` will probably meet your needs better

you can also do something like:

```
RolesMessages.find_by_sql("query goes here")
```

(I prefer to make the query myself... call me crazy)

Comment: So I realize this is kind of old, but find_by_sql produces an array output instead of an ActiveRecord, which may not be the best solution.